# Creating Angular 2 components in markup

Tags: typescript, angular

How do I create my components in (nested) markup?

`<component-name [field]="value"></component-name>` doesn't seem to work.

Consider the following example:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: "hero-detail",
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `Name: {{name}}`
})
class HeroDetail {
  public name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, HeroDetail],
  template:`
    <h1>Heroes</h1>
    <hero-detail [name]="name"></hero-detail>
  `
})
class AppComponent { 
    public name: string = "Funky name";
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Outputs:

`Name:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark `name` property of `HeroDetail` component as "input". For this you can use either [`@Input`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L1019) decorator or [`inputs`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L467) property of [`@Component`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L823) decorator. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/242qUnJNCp5dn8cTMqYi?p=preview).

```ts
import {bootstrap, Component, Input} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: "hero-detail",
  template: `Name: {{name}}`,
  // inputs: ['name'] <-- you can use "inputs" property in @Component
})
class HeroDetail {
  @Input() name: string; // or @Input property decorator
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [HeroDetail],
  template:`
    <h1>Heroes</h1>
    <hero-detail [name]="name"></hero-detail>
  `
})
class AppComponent { 
    public name: string = "Funky name";
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```